# Angular Universal, Buttons not working on pre render

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, universal

I'm trying to do a Angular SSR application, that requests from the Wordpress API the pages and render them on the client using SSR, for it to hide the calls to the API, I was trying to use prerender but the click event doesn't seem to work, sorry for my bad English and thank you in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and add the relevant piece of code. here is the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you need help with the formatting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.